# VB.Net Lambda query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda

I know I can change a query like this

```
Dim myList As List(Of Tickets) = (From a In db.myTable
                  Where a.ID = id AndAlso a.IsOnline = True).ToList
```

to lambda

```
Dim myList as List(of Tickets) = db.Where(Function(x) x.ID = id ANDAlso a.IsOnline = true).ToList
```

How do I write the lambda version and tell it to create a new object with the results?? like this:

```
Dim myList As List(Of Tickets) = (From a In db.myTable
                             Where a.ID = id AndAlso a.IsOnline = True
                             Select New TicketType With {
                                       .Id = a.rsID.ToString,
                                       .Title = a.rsTitle}).ToList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `Select()` method:

```
.Select(Function(x) New TicketType With { ... })
```

Comment: so    .Where(Function(x) ...).Select(Function(y) ..)    like that with both ?

Comment: @ScottSelby: Exactly.  Each of these extension methods operates on and returns `IEnumerable(Of T)`, so you can chain them to your heart's content.